# Android - Programming Style - RecyclerView - Use SetText in ViewHolder or in onBindViewHolder?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-recyclerview, settext, android-viewholder

When setting `OnClickListeners` to items in the `RecyclerView` it's recommended to do that in the inner class like this:

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemVIew);
    nameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

When I see code for setting text it's usually in the `onBindViewHolder` method:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SetPlayerNameViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.nameTextView.setText(String.valueOf("Random Text"));
}
```

If the text never changes, shouldn't it be in the inner class?

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemVIew);
    nameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    nameTextView.setText(String.valueOf("Random Text"));
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

**Edit: And what if you retrieve a value that is different for all `TextViews`, but should not be updated when the `RecyclerView` reloads it**

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemVIew);
    nameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);

    // Not the actual methods, but to make it more readable
    int i = itemView.getPosition()
    String randomText = getTextFromDatabaseWhereRowIs(i)

    nameTextView.setText(String.valueOf(randomText));
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you are right...

**1.** `onBindViewHolder(..., int position)` get called for `individual` items of `RecyclerView`. If your `text` is different for each `item` then you should use it from `onBindViewHolder()` using `position` to get the correct `text`.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SetPlayerNameViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String item = YourList.get(position); // For example YourList is an ArrayList of String
    holder.nameTextView.setText(item);
}
```

**2.** If `text` is fixed for each `item` then you can set it from `ViewHolder` as you said or you can make it fix from TextView `XML` using `android:text="YOUR_TEXT"`.

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemVIew);
    nameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    nameTextView.setText("Random Text");
}
```

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

> This method internally calls onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder, int) to update the RecyclerView.ViewHolder contents with the item at the given position and also sets up some private fields to be used by RecyclerView.

The ViewHolder you are received from the parameter, comes from the `Cache` or the [`RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool.html).

> RecycledViewPool lets you share Views between multiple RecyclerViews.
>   If you want to recycle views across RecyclerViews, create an instance of RecycledViewPool and use setRecycledViewPool(RecycledViewPool).
>   RecyclerView automatically creates a pool for itself if you don't provide one.

So If you are not using the same `viewType` and the same layout across different `RecyclerView` where the text of the `TextView` is different in each `RecyclerView`, then you are right. But if you are doing so, Then `RecyclerView` might not call `createViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)` as it might a viewHolder from the `RecycledViewPool`. In that case you can set the text value in [`onViewAttachedToWindow(VH holder)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onViewAttachedToWindow(VH))